# How would you style the "body" of multiple pages in a reactjs app without having them overlapping each other?

Tags: css, reactjs, mern

Okay, guys.

Having tried multiple different ways in various different ways, I came here for the experts who definitely knows the answer for this simple problem.

So, the issue I'm having is that whenever I try to add background images and other properties to the "body" of the pages in the app that I'm creating, , it adds only the CSS of a single page for all the other pages.

If this question sounds too hefty, let me boil it down to this:

How can you add different styles for the **body** tag of the multiple pages?

To make things easy for you, you can have a look at the following code:

Here's the Login file

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { login } from '../../../actions/auth';

import './Login.css';




const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })


    const { email, password } = formData;

    const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        login(email, password)
    }

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    }



    return (

        <Fragment>

            <section className="bodyLogin">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>

                    <input type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Email.............."
                        value={email}
                        onChange={e => onChange(e)}

                        required /> <br /><br />

                    <input type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Password.............."
                        value={password}
                        onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                        required /><br /><br />

                    <div className="account-login">
                        <p>Don't have an account? <span><Link to="/register">Register</Link> </span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="btn-login">
                        <input type="submit" name="Login" defaultValue="Log In" />
                        <Link to="/"><input type="button" name="Back" defaultValue="Back" /> </Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>

        </Fragment>



    )



}


Login.propTypes = {

    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool


}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({

    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});




export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

Its css file

```
html,
.Login>.bodyLogin {

    height: 100%;


}


.Login>.bodyLogin {


    background-image: url("/client/src/components/images/undraw_people_tax5.png"), url("/client/src/components/images/undraw_together_j0gj.png");

    background-size: 80% 100%, 101% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 1% 60%, 80% 110%;





}
```

Now, I want to add different background images for other pages. But I get the same image that I used for the Login.js.

Modules didn't really work. Do you know a way to go about solving this?

I add the following functional component like this:

```
const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = url("../../images/undraw_people_tax5.png");
    })
```

But I was shoved with this red error!

[image]

Comment: just to be clear, you are asking how to limit the css styles to a single component?

Comment: Hello Yousaf. Well, Yes, I want to limit the css styles to a single component. I successfully did it for other tags ,but for the background images in the body tag., I'm having some really hard time figuring it out.

Comment: take a look at [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

Comment: Tried already, didn't work

Comment: Add URL in quotes like `...backgroundImage = 'url("....")'`. Also add `[]` as second parameter to `useEffect()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended React practice for controlling markup outside React is [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

In each of your component, include a `Helmet` that defines body styles (and other attributes) like this:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
function Page(props) {
    const bgColor = '#ddd';
    return (
       <div class="page">
                <Helmet>
                    {/* Define inline CSS for body tag */}
                    <body style="background-color: #ddd" />
                    {/* Or include in-file CSS */}
                    <style>
                       {`
                            body {
                                background-color: ${bgColor};
                            }
                       `}
                    </style>
                </Helmet>
                {/* Rest of your component content goes here ... /*}
       </div>
    );
}
```

`Helmet` can be nested inside each other via component hierarchy and function like CSS cascading, so you can customize `body` at any level deep (among child components) as you like.

Note: This approach is only suitable for defining CSS on markup outside React like `html`, `body`. Inside React components follow better methods to import controlled CSS like *CSS Modules*, *Styled Component*, etc.

#### Update 1

In your case, place the `Helmet` as first child of `<Fragment>`:

```
     <Fragment>
         <Helmet>
             <style>
                {`
                   html, body {
                       height: 100%;
                  }

                 body {
                    background-image: url("/client/src/components/images/undraw_people_tax5.png"), url("/client/src/components/images/undraw_together_j0gj.png");
                    background-size: 80% 100%, 101% 100%;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-position: 1% 60%, 80% 110%;
                  }
                `}
            </style>
         </Helmet>
       {/* Rest of your Fragment goes here ... /*}
     </Fragment>
```

#### Update 2

If you want to use CSS file, instead of inlining everything like this, replace your `import './Login.css)` with this:

```
 const css = require('./Login.css').toString();
```

Then your `<style>` can just include the CSS string:

```
                <Helmet>
                    <style>
                        {css}
                    </style>
                </Helmet>
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen! Now that function Page is just a dummy variable right?

Comment: So, if I use this, would I be able to have different styles for multiple pages?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess `function Page` is a React component representing your page. Yes you can have different styles for every page, or even inside each page. I added comment about this

Comment: Gotcha! I'll get going with this and see how it ends up and surely will let you know

Comment: Did you insert `Helmet` as the first child inside `<Fragment>`?

Comment: No I didn't put it there Ngyuen. I placed it above the beginning of the component function

Comment: See my instructions added to answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216415/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-son-nguyen).

Comment: Hey Nguyen, your update 1 worked! Thanks for everything!

Comment: ```const css = require('./Login.css').toString();```
This returns just [object Object] and no string. :-/

Comment: I included `in-file CSS` without using `react-helmet` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use different class names and also keep your styles limited to your pages by not adding any page styles in the global style. What I am saying is, create a container for every page. And in that container keep all of your page elements and styles. I Hope, it would help.

Comment: Then, It's difficult to answer it without seeing your code.

Comment: Hey Sha, thanks for the concern over the matter. I'll give you the required code ASAP

Comment: Sha, Code was just added.

Comment: Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Add following statement in each component

class based component

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(/* image path */)';
}
```

functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
   document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(/* image path */)';
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Valibhav for the answer. I'll try this and let you know whether it works

Comment: Where should you add this to? Inside the component function or outside of it? Just a novice here!

Comment: Hey this didn't work. Don't know why. It didn't work somehow

Comment: Hello Valibhav, it gives this URL is not defined error when I use the functional component. How would you solve that?

Comment: Sure! where to add the image though?

Comment: We might have to start a chat in a room?

Comment: How can we move this to a chat?

Comment: Valibhav, I added the error I get. Check the recent edit I made in the original post. Thanks